# How to display the "Invalid numbers with conditions" in Java?

Tags: java

Here is the problem with my output:

```
Enter number of students: 3
Enter the grade for student 1:
-2
Invalid grade, try again...
Enter the grade for student 2:
-3
Invalid grade, try again...
Enter the grade for student 3:
110
Invalid grade, try again...
The average is 35.0
```

But in the sample output session as follow:

```
Enter number of students: 3
Enter the grade for student 1:
55
Enter the grade for student 2:
108
Invalid grade, try again...
Enter the grade for student 2:
56
Enter the grade for student 3:
57
The average is 56.0
```

Can you see the `-2`, the `-3` and `110` did not break the loop and it kept asking for new input? Instead of showing `108` on the sample and immediately break the loop and ask user to prompt the input of `student 2` again.

Here is my code:

```java
public static int theSumOfGrade(int[] newArray, int grade) {
    int sumGrade = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) { // for i < array length
        sumOfGrade += newArray[i];  // the sum will be added up with all the values inside the array
    }
    return sumOfGrade;
}

public static int[] getNumberOfStudentsArray(Scanner input) { // Number of students input method
    System.out.printf("Enter number of students: "); // Prompt the number of students from the user
    int numberOfStudents= input.nextInt(); // Scanner Object in with numberOfStudents variable

    int studentGrades[] = new int[numberOfStudents]; // Assign to new Array

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the grade for student " + (i+1) + ":"  );
        studentGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
//        for (int j = 0; j < studentGrades.length; j++) {
//        }
        if (studentGrades[i] < 0 || studentGrades[i] > 100) {
            System.out.println("Invalid grade, try again");
            continue;
        }
    }
    return studentGrades;
} // end of getNumberOfStudentsArray()
```

Comment: write `i--` before the `continue` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the input is wrong then `int i` should not get the increment. So you can do it as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents;) { // removed increment from here
            System.out.println("Enter the grade for student " + (i+1) + ":"  );
            studentGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
            if (studentGrades[i] < 0 || studentGrades[i] > 100) {
                System.out.println("Invalid grade, try again");
                continue;
            }
            i++; // Increment only when entered value is correct
        }
```

Comment: This is absolutely useful! Thank you a lot and have a good day.